# Shortest path between two points through N checkpoints in a matrix

Tags: c++, shortest-path

How to find shortest path between two points, namely S and D, in a matrix ? It should pass through multiple checkpoints named &. It cannot pass through G. * represents an open gate. Paths can pass through destination and checkpoints any number of times.

Example:

> > ```
> > GGGGG
> > GS**G  
> > GGDGG  
> > G**&G  
> > GGGGG
> > ```

Output for this matrix should be 6.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: That's basically the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: You could systemically check every possible route choice storing the results and then select which set of route choices is the shortest from among those which succeeded.

Comment: The A* path-finding algorithm and its variants may also be useful here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is easy when you only have one waypoint that you have to visit. You find the path (using A*, for instance) to the waypoint and then the path from the waypoint to the goal.

When the number of waypoints increases the problem gets exponentially harder, because you have to consider visiting any waypoint next. This becomes the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

General approaches are to approximate the shortest solution by choosing the waypoint that looks best next, or to find the optimal solution by trying all possibilities. (The wikipedia page linked above goes into these.)

But, you'll need to do your own research on these -- far beyond the scope of what we can help you with here.

A good next step would be to choose an approach to implement. If you don't understand it you can ask specifically how some aspect of the approach works. But, full solutions are complicated, so you won't get much coding help with such a general question.

---

For optimal solutions your best bet is a depth-first branch and bound search. This is a depth-first search with pruning - eliminating paths that are guaranteed to be worse that your best solution so far. You can find information about the algorithm on many pages, including [this one](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_63.html), but if you have a question about how to implement a specific algorithm you should start working on that algorithm and then ask a *new* question about that.

Your question of *how* to do it has been answered by both questions here at the same level of detail of your own question. Nobody is going to post a full source-code solution for you here, as this sounds like a class assignment. When you start implementing something and get stuck, feel free to ask another question about exactly what is getting you stuck.

Comment: I have to implement it for a 100*100 matrix.So if you have any prototype code please post it in comment..

Comment: @NavinPrashath, oh my goodness. What is the upper bound for the number of checkpoints?

Comment: The key difficulty is how many checkpoints you have. The more checkpoints the harder the problem. I have tons of code that could be used for this problem, but it's far too large to post here.

Comment: Optimal or suboptimal solutions?

Comment: Gosh, 18 checkpoints means 6402373705728000 possible orders to visit them. If you do not try to implement something like branch and bound, stick to really simple ideas.

Comment: You could formulate it as a TSP and solve it as such. I used this code, which gives really good heuristic solutions: http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/research/LKH/

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, you need to do 2 steps:

1. Find the shortest path from your source node to the other using **Breadth First Search (BFS)**;
2. Reconstruct the graph with only `S`, `D` and `&` points, and the weight of each edge is **the shortest path** between them in original path you calculated in the first step, then the problem becomes a typical [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably very late but after reading this thread, I found a solution for my grid searching problem with n-checkpoints (I have tested on only 3 waypoint + final stop) and shared my answer as I thought it would be relevant to this thread.
I have used BFS to find the minDistance and then isolated all cases(grid with start and end point) then permutate all the cases for the shortest path in the grid while covering all the waypoints (F) + endpoint (H).
My starting position is not 0,0. It is (C) in my case!!

Hope this helps!!

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,row,col,dist):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.dist = dist
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.row}, {self.col}, {self.dist})"
        
def minDistance(grid,src):
    source = src
    visited = [[False for _ in range(len(grid[0]))]
                for _ in range(len(grid))]
    
    queue = []
    queue.append(source)
    visited[source.row][source.col] = True
    
    while len(queue) != 0:
        source = queue.pop(0)
        
        if grid[source.row][source.col] == "F":
            return source.dist
        #up
        if isValid(source.row-1,source.col,grid,visited):
            queue.append(Item(source.row-1,source.col,source.dist+1))
            visited[source.row-1][source.col] = True
        #down
        if isValid(source.row+1,source.col,grid,visited):
            queue.append(Item(source.row+1,source.col,source.dist+1))
            visited[source.row+1][source.col] = True
        #left
        if isValid(source.row,source.col-1,grid,visited):
            queue.append(Item(source.row,source.col-1,source.dist+1))
            visited[source.row][source.col-1] = True
        #right
        if isValid(source.row,source.col+1,grid,visited):
            queue.append(Item(source.row,source.col+1,source.dist+1))
            visited[source.row][source.col+1] = True
    return -1
def isValid(x,y,grid,visited):
    if ((x>=0 and y>=0) and (x<len(grid) and y<len(grid[0])) and (visited[x][y] == False)):
        return True
    return False
def findFood(grid,val):
    food = []
    for x in range(len(grid)):
        for y in range(len(grid[0])):
            if grid[x][y] == val:
                food.append(Item(x,y,0))
    return food
def createGrid(foodLoc,source,grid,val):
    g1 = [['O' for _ in range(len(grid[0]))] for _ in range(len(grid))]
    g1[foodLoc.row][foodLoc.col] = val
    g1[source.row][source.col] = "C"
    return g1
from itertools import permutations
def findMinDistance(grid, source):
    food = findFood(grid,"F")
    home = findFood(grid,"H")[0]
    Path = permutations(food,len(food))
    minDis = []
    for y in list(Path):
        src = source
        dist = 0
        for x in list(y)+[home]:
            currGrid = createGrid(x,src,grid,"F")
            di = minDistance(currGrid,src)
            if di != -1:
                dist += di
                
                src = x
        #reach home
        minDis.append(dist)
    print(minDis)
    return min(minDis)
    
    
grid = [list(x) for x in "FOOF OCOO OOOH FOOO".split()]
source = Item(1,1,0)
res = findMinDistance(grid,source)
print(res)
```

Comment: referred this for ***BFS code*** [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-distance-two-cells-matrix-grid/)

Comment: The op didn't specify it in his question, but he tagged it C++. Your code is python however. Nevertheless, thank you for sharing your solution.