# Finding the shortest path between 2 points namely S and G?

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, a-star

Finding the shortest path between 2 points namely S and G? It SHOULD pass through points named @. The allowed pathway is denoted as . and the blocked pathway is denoted as #. The upper cap of the number of points inbetween is 19.

```
           Example: 

             input 
             ########
             #@....G#
             ##.##@##
             #..@..S#
             #@.....#
             ########
```

Comment: There are numerous duplicates of this question, but I think this one is the most appropriate for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428848/shortest-path-between-two-points-through-n-checkpoints-in-a-matrix. To find others, do a Google search with "site:stackoverflow.com shortest path checkpoint".

Answer (score 0):

"It should pass through points named @" - If you can elaborate more on this. OR for the example above, what is the expected solution.
Also statement says "blocked pathway is denoted as X" and in example, we see "#". I believe you meant # as X.
I assume direction of movement would be left, right, up and down.

This can be solved by breadth first search (BFS) on the grid.
Start from S and explore all paths level by level based on given constraint where you can reach and where you can't reach.

We can take two arrays or lists say currentLevel and nextLevel. And a variable, say levelCount.
Store position S in currentLevel.

1. Loop through positions in currentLevel one by one. If it is G, levelCount is the shortest path.
   Else, for all safe positions (left, right, up and down) where we can reach and store them in 
   nextLevel. "safe position" means that it should not be X, should not go beyond the given
   grid extent (i.e. position index should not less than zero and not greater than length)
   or other constraint given in problem.
2. Set currentLevel to nextLevel, increment levelCount and clear nextLevel. Go to step 1.

Comment: Hi, what @ denotes is like "checkpoints" meaning that when going from the starting to end, we HAVE to pass through all @s. Lets say for the example above, the output has to be 16. I used A* algorithm to solve the basic shortest route problem without the checkpoints by assigning movement values and distance from the endpoint but I'm not able to solve the checkpoint problem.